# Python sort list based on values in another list with matching pattern

Tags: python-3.8

I have a list `L1`:

```
['Apr21_Dzr', 'Aug20_Dzr', 'Dec20_Dzr',
       'Nov20_Dzr', 'Oct20_Dzr', 'Sep20_Dzr']
```

I have another master list, `L2`:

```
['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
```

I want to sort the list `L1` to get the following:

```
['Aug20_Dzr', 'Sep20_Dzr', 'Oct20_Dzr', 'Nov20_Dzr', 'Dec20_Dzr', 'Apr21_Dzr']
```

i.e. sort the `L1` so that it follows the pattern in list `L2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work for you

```
sorted_L1 = sorted(L1, key=lambda x: 12 * int(x[2:].split('_')[0]) + L2.index(x[:3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an intermediate list and sort the elements of l1 within this new list.You can use two nested for loops for this.Then clear l1 and copy the new list to l1.I have shown below how i did it in my python shell.

```
>>> new_list=[]
>>> for element in l2:
        for data in l1:
            if data[:3] == element:
                new_list.append(data)


>>> print(new_list)
['Aug20_Dzr', 'Sep20_Dzr', 'Oct20_Dzr', 'Nov20_Dzr', 'Dec20_Dzr', 'Apr21_Dzr']
>>> l1.clear()
>>> l1 = new_list.copy()
>>> print(l1)
['Aug20_Dzr', 'Sep20_Dzr', 'Oct20_Dzr', 'Nov20_Dzr', 'Dec20_Dzr', 'Apr21_Dzr']
```